# No player_position events received with Deezer JavaScript SDK on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, deezer

When I subscribe to `player_position` events in my InApp using the JavaScript SDK with `DZ.Event.subscribe('player_position', ...)`, the event callback is never triggered when the InApp is running inside the Deezer app in an iPhone. It is triggered on Android and desktop however. Should the event be fired on iOS too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it should also be fired on iOS. This is a bug in the iOS application. It will be fixed in 5.4.x release (not next one, the next next one).

Comment: Do you have any (even rough) estimate when the fix will be released? In some weeks or in some months?

Comment: The version should be publish in roughly one 3 weeks.

Comment: I also noticed that the `player_play` event is not fired on iOS. Will that one be fixed in the same release too?