# Deezer Javascript SDK playAlbum offset ignored on mobile

Tags: javascript, deezer

In my Deezer InApp, when I call the `DZ.player.playAlbum` method with a non-zero offset, e.g. `DZ.player.playAlbum(10008268, true, 0, 13)`, the playback starts at the given offset on the Deezer desktop site, but in the mobile apps (both Android and iOS) the playback starts from the beginning. Is the offset not supported on mobile? Is there any workaround solution? This would be an important feature for me to have.

Comment: Can you please add some of your code?

Comment: What else do you want me to add? That one call is all there is to triggering the playback.

Comment: Try with DZ.player.seek http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/controls. I have not tested, but this is another function to change the position of the player.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround based on `DZ.player.seek` that seems to work on Android, but it won't work on iOS until [receiving player_position events works on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708776/no-player-position-events-received-with-deezer-javascript-sdk-on-ios):

```
const album = 10008268;
const trackIndex = 0;
const offset = 10;

DZ.player.playAlbum(album, true, trackIndex, tracklist => {
  if (offset) {
    DZ.Event.subscribe('player_position', args => {
      const position = args ? args[0] : null;
      if (position) {
        const currentTrack = tracklist.tracks[trackIndex];
        const currentTrackLength = Number(currentTrack.duration);
        const seekOffset = offset / currentTrackLength * 100;
        DZ.player.seek(seekOffset);

        setTimeout(() => DZ.Event.unsubscribe('player_position'));
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Listening for `player_position` events is needed because calling `DZ.player.seek` seems to have no effect if the player position is 0. Also, I need to use `setTimeout` for unsubscribing outside of the callback function, otherwise I get an exception.

Comment: Did you try with the 'current_track' event ?

Comment: I tried the 'current_track' event but it didn't work, seeking after receiving the event had no effect. I suspect the event is fired before the player position has moved from 0.

Comment: The offset is working on iOS with my tests, but for Android, you can use the `player_play` event, with the `once` parameter set to `true` like so: `DZ.Event.subscribe(event, callback, once);`

Comment: Thanks, using the `player_play` event works on Android, but unfortunately I don't see the event fired on iOS. How come the offset works for you on iOS, do you have some special version of the SDK?

Comment: My call is slightly different than yours, try `DZ.player.playAlbum(10008268, 0, 13)`

Comment: I tried calling without the autoplay flag like you have, but the playback still starts from the beginning.